# SQL main query returns duplicates when subquery with max finds a tie

Tags: sql, duplicates

My sql query is returning duplicate rows. I don't know how to eliminate the duplicates.
I'm using a subquery with MAX and rownum=1 to find a transformer's biggest load.
Whenever there are two records that tie for the biggest load, the main query returns duplicates.

Here is what I'm trying (edited to try to follow suggestions below):

```
select t1.type, t2.loc, t3.load, t4.size
from t1
  join t2 on t2.id1 = t1.id1
  join t3 on t3.id1 = t1.id1
  join t4 on t4.id2 = t1.id2
where t1.type = 'T'
  and t2.status = 'A'
  and t3.load = (select max(t3.load) 
                 from t3 
                 where t3.id1 = t1.id1 
                   and rownum = 1);
```

My table structure has:

```
table: t1 cols: id1, id2, type
table: t2 cols: id1, loc, status
table: t3 cols: id1, load
table: t4 cols: id2, size
```

Maybe my tables are somehow double linked together? I don't use SQL very often. Maybe there is a better way  to do this?

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. And don't forget to add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: Also, note that tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: Your query is a tad hard to read, because of those comma-separated joins we used in the 1980s and the generic table aliases. Use explicit joins instead and use mnemonic alias names, e.g. lch for loc_hist and ldh for load_hist. Anyway, you are selecting all load_hist rows the calc_load_vl of which equals the top calc_load_vl for the eqseq_id in the last two years. These rows can span many years. To each of these rows you are joining all non-closed WA0 loc_hist rows. This may or may not be what you want. I neither know your tables nor do I know your data nor what the query is supposed to select.

Comment: A very simple way to eliminate duplicates might be simply `SELECT DISTINCT` – though still your query might have some issues, you might want to check once more.

Comment: Surely all those columns, and probably tables, are not needed to demonstrate the problem. Please reduce your query to the absolute minimum required by first abstracting the problem to tables with names `A`, `B` etc, and column names like `id`, `col1` etc, then stripping out everything you can. This will a) clarify the problem, b) make it easier/more likely for us to provide an answer and c) most importantly make this question more broadly useful to future visitors the wider community.

Comment: I've tried to remove all the extraneous stuff by editing my original post.

Comment: @Garth could you post a sample of the results and the data?